# How do I extract a column from text using Python?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python programing. Wrote this script by searching in python docs from internet.

Could anybody please help me to get only the second column as output of "ps aux" command(ie only the PID Column).

```
#script to print the processid
import os
import commands
out=commands.getoutput('ps aux') # to get the process listing in out
#print out
#print out[2] #print only second column from out
print out[:2] 

output of "print out" statement
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   5728  1068 ?        Ss   Oct13   0:07 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct13   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct13   0:00 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct13   0:11 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct13   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct13   0:00 [migration/1]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is actually very easy using `AWK` if you have access to it. `ps aux | awk {'print $1'}`

Comment: @RussellDias you mean `ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` ($0 is full line, so $1 is the first column, not second...)

Comment: @Tom: Doh! I had `$2` but changed it to `$1` for some odd reason (I think I tested it on cygwin which does not output `USER`) :( eh can't update it now

Comment: @ANV you probably want to use `out = subprocess.check_output('ps aux')` too. The commands module is deprecated.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks Tom. I tried but got the following errors

Comment: >>> import subprocess
>>> out1=subprocess.check_output('ps aux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I think check_output is new in 2.7. I think the following should be equivalent: `out = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]` (use Python 2.7 :)

Comment: @Tom: Yes the python which i am currently using is,$ python -V
Python 2.6.4rc2. Any way Thanks Tom i will try this this command  also.

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` and `splitlines()` (to convert the string into a list of lines, and the list of lines into a list of columns that you can then index as needed):

```
>>> for line in out.splitlines():
...     fields = line.split()
...     if len(fields) >= 2:
...         print fields[1]


PID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My actual need is to print the last column which is the command column. If we try the method you suggested then we get only the portion of the command column. eg:- the command column has got line as  /bin/bash /bin/test.txt but it only prints /bin/bash. i wanted actually the whole command column. any suggestions would be helpful.Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: That is simple enough.  Either print line[65:] or fields[10:].

Comment: Thanks exactly that's what i am looking for. If you don't mind, could you please let me know how you got the count(ie 65). Regarding fields i understood its the 10 value in the list field.

Comment: `line` is a string, so `line[65:]` is everything in `line` from character number 65 onwards. I presume @RaymondHettinger found that out by counting them or cutting and pasting and using `len("...")`...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments this is very straightforward to do using `awk`:

```
ps aux | awk {'print $2'}
```

However, here is also a python solution using a list comprehension, which gives you a list of PID's:

```
>>> [col.split()[1] for col in out.splitlines()]
['PID', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```