# Regex to find the String starting with special word from subprocess output

Tags: python, regex

In the code,I am searching for a string starting with `FAILED`.
The `tt` variable holds the stdoutput of the `subprocess.Popen`.
I have tried `re.serach` & `re.match` but it yields `None` as a return value.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re

def cbk():
    with open('GDPC.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tt = subprocess.Popen(['/grid/it/bin/cyberarksdk.sh' ,  'chk', line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
            #pat_match=re.search(".*FAILED:\s+", tt)
            pat_match=re.search(r'(^FAILED:)\s+', tt)
            print pat_match

cbk()
```

> Output of the above script:

```
$./cyberCheck.py
None
None
None
None
```

> The output of the Variable `tt`:

```
FAILED: Account/host myserver1 does not exist inside cyberark.
1 102_2923 DS-KS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT Operating System-DS-Unix-RootAccounts-SSH-myserver2-root
```

Intent: Just to search the Line starting with `FAILED` string and cut the third column that's myserevr1 and put into a file `file1`, Similarly any Line starting with `1` cut the `myserver2` and put into another file `file2`.

Note: `GDPC.txt` contains the server names.

Comment: Does `pat_match=re.search(r'(^FAILED:)\s+', tt, re.MULTILINE)` work?

Comment: @Jan, let me check that.

Comment: @Jan, No .. its still gives same `None` in the return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for now to get the the line containing `FAILED`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re
##################
def cbk():
    with open('GDPC.txt', 'rw') as f:
        for line in f:
            tt = subprocess.Popen(['/grid/it/bin/cyberarksdk.sh' ,  'chk', line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
            pm = re.search('FAILED.*', tt)
            if pm:
                 #print  pm.group(0)
                 for line in pm.group(0).splitlines():
                     col = line.split()
                     if len(col) >=3:
                         print col[2]
cbk()
```

> Below is the output :

```
$./cyberCheck.py
myserver1 
myserver2 
myserver3
```

> Solution: Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831312/7995721

Use split() and splitlines() (to convert the string into a list of lines, and the list of lines into a list of columns that you can then index as needed):